# Is it possible to use HDMI out and DisplayPort with daisy chaining simultaneously?

Tags: display, hdmi, graphics, displayport

Specifically, I'd be interested in if such a combo works on notebooks with graphic adapters such as the Geforce GTX 850M .

E.G.:
Monitor 1: internal 
Monitor 2: external via HDMI 
Monitor 3,4,5... external via DisplayPort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it would work because HDMI doesn't support daisy chaining, and it is the first media type encountered in the chain. The best case I could see would be the first monitor supports mirroring from HDMI to the displayport connector. So you could have a second monitor, but the third and consecutive monitors would just be a clone of the second monitor.

As I understand it, DisplayPort paired with the correct monitors support daisy chaining. HDMI doesn't support this at all. Also, not all DisplayPort monitors support daisy chaining, some only allow cloning.

Comment: Do you know any resouce where the details could be checked? I went to the official displayport site but I couldn't find anything about my use case. Afaik what works for sure is to have a configuration using 1 external monitor on each the HDMI and the DisplayPort + internal display OR internal display + multiple daisy chained monitors.

Comment: I don't know of any 'offical' sources, but I know that HDMI simply doesn't support daisy chaining. That is one of the reasons DisplayPort was created. 1 HDMI port = 1 HDMI monitor. DisplayPort chaining seems to be more dependant on the monitors themselves rather than anything else. That's just been my experiencing working in company that began adopting DP very early.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you advice. It saved me a lot of money as notebooks with DisplayPorts tend to be more expensive than equivalents that only have DVI/VGA.